# Having nested pipelines in the same repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am working on a micro-services project, each service has its own pipeline because it gets deployed to a server of its own, we have each project in its own repository on gitlab with its own `.gitlab-ci.yml` but I want to collect all of these services in a single repository to make them easier to maintain and trigger a deployment of all the services when a commit is pushed.

The issue is I don't want to have a big fat yaml file that contains the build & deployment process of each service but instead keep the yaml files in the services folders and have a yaml file on the root that references them, i.e.:

```
| service1
  | service1-code
  | .gitlab-ci.yaml << build process for service1
| service2
  | service2-code
  | .gitlab-ci.yaml << build process for service2
| .gitlab-ci.yaml << reference to service1/yaml & service2/yaml
```

Is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way for GitLab to do this, and there is an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18157) to add this feature for monorepos.

Comment: I was hoping someone would have found a way around it

Answer (score 0):

> (...) keep the yaml files in the services folders and have a yaml file on the root that references them

Just found this [comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18157#note_12297400) on GitLab by [robindegen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2037508/robin-degen).

> We create separate repositories, and a parent main repository that has
>   them as submodules. This works just fine for doing CI on subsets. When
>   we push to master on the main repo (to update the submodules), a full
>   CI run is done on everything, including integration tests.

I recon a CI clone includes submodules so this would just work. So if you already have a repo per project; have your cake and eat it too!